# ASP.Net MVC Extension methods not being recognised in Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I am building a site using Umbraco CMS (version 7.2.1).

I have published on two servers: server A and server B

Server A having IIS8, .NET Version: 4.0.30319.34014 and Windows Server 2013 as the Operating System.

Server B having IIS7.5, .NET Version:4.0.30319.34209, and Windows Server 2008 Standard Release 2 as the Operating System.

I am publishing via web deploy, exactly on these two servers; Server A is working fine, and on Server B there are errors which are occurring, which seems that the extension methods through `CurrentPage` are not being found.

One of the errors can be seen in the below screenshot: 
[image]

I appreciate any help on what might be causing these errors to occur.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this is actually demonstrating that ```CurrentPage.Ancestors()``` does not have an extension method of ```.Any()```. Make sure you have referenced. Do you have a reference to ```System.Linq```?

Comment: Yes. It is working on a server online and even locally. The problem is on server B